# Prove that there are no such different positive numbers that satisfy both $a+b=c+d$ and $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a,b,c$ and $d$ are all different and positive. Prove that it can't be true that equalities $a+b=c+d$ and $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$ are both correct at the same time. I sadly don't know how to start trying to solve this and haven't really tried much, so I'd like to get some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's not needed.

Comment: @egreg Yeah, had a brain misfire. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You can derive that $ab=cd$ (how?)

Then
\begin{cases}
a-c=d-b\\
ab-cd=0
\end{cases}
If you consider this as a linear system in $a$ and $c$, …

Comment: $a+b=c+d$ and $ab=cd$ would be nice too (consider quadratic polynomials). In particular combining the result of Igor's answer with the expanded version of $(a+b)^2=(c+d)^2$ results in the beginning of this answer.

Comment: @anon Good remark.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's next after I've found out that the system of equations is correct? How to finish the proof?

Comment: @mathh The system's determinant is $b-d$; but if you assume $b\ne d$, you find that the solution is $a=d$ and $b=c$.

Comment: This is how I've continued the solution after your system of equations: $$a+b=c+d \Rightarrow (a+b)^2=(c+d)^2\\ \begin{cases} (a+b)^2=(c+d)^2\\ ab=cd \end{cases} \Rightarrow a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2 \Rightarrow (a+c)(a-c)=(d+b)(d-b)\\ \begin{cases} (a+c)(a-c)=(d+b)(d-b)\\ a-c=d-b \end{cases} \Rightarrow a+c = d+b\\ \begin{cases} a+c=d+b\\ a+b=c+d \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}a=d\\b=c\end{cases}$$

Comment: @mathh A bit complicated, but correct; so you have a contradiction, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I've shown that if $\begin{cases}a+b=c+d\\ a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3\end{cases}$, then $\begin{cases}a=d\\b=c\end{cases}$, which contradicts that $a,b,c,d$ can be different.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "the system's determinant"? What is that?

Comment: @mathh If $a$ and $c$ are considered as unknowns, the system's matrix is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1\\b&-d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Answer (score 8):

Hint: factor the LHS and the RHS and see what happens.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is just to replace $d$ by $a+b-c$ and then factor $a^3+b^3-c^3-d^3=0$. The result is
$$
- 3(a + b)(a - c)(b - c)=0.
$$
The result follows.

Answer (score 4):

If we have $a+b=c+d$ with all different positive integers, we may as well assume $a$ is the smallest of them and write $c=a+r$ and $d=a+s$ with positive integers $r$ and $s$, in which case $b=a+r+s$.  A modicum of algebra shows that

$$(a^3+b^3)-(c^3+d^3)=6ars+3r^2s+3rs^2\gt0$$

so $a^3+b^3$ cannot equal $c^3+d^3$.