# Prove that there are 4 differents positive integers (a,b,c and d) that satisfy both conditions: "a² + b² = c² + d²" and "a+b=c+d"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604503/prove-that-there-are-no-such-different-positive-numbers-that-satisfy-both-ab-c) but what I'm looking for is a little bit different...

Besides trying to prove that both these conditions are satisfied and a,b,c and d are four different positive integers:

> a² + b² = c² + d²
>
> a + b = c + d

I would like to prove that this holds for n terms (number of integer in each side) like:

> for n = 3
>
> a² + b² + c² = d² + e² + f²
>
> a + b + c = d + e + f

and so on...

Thanks guys!

Comment: Itls not even possible to find four different real numbers with this property.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for answering! What I mean is: you cant find four different, but can you find 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a + b)^2 = (c + d )^2 : ab = cd

a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2 : a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = c^2 -2cd + d^2 : a-b = c-d or

a-b = d-c

a + b = c + d , a - b = c - d : a =c : b = d

a + b = c + d , a - b = d - c : a = 0 , d = 0 , b = c

So it is not possible for different integers

Comment: Or even four different real numbers or four different complex numbers...

Comment: I mean integer answers are asked

Comment: Sure, I was just noting that your proof shows a stronger result.

Comment: Only integer. Yeah, I got it, it's not possible, but if we cant find 4 number, can we find 6 (n=3)?

Comment: I've realized that for n=3, we ended up in the same situation as n=2 because either the new 2 number are different and the conditions are not satisfied or the new 2 number are equal and the situation remains the same. Thanks @someone for answering!