# Prove that two sets, $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$, are equal if...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove that two sets, $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$, are equal if

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 =\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2$, and
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i =\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i $
>
> $X,Y \in \mathbb{Z}_+$

I know that its trivial for n=1. For n=2 the proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530828/prove-that-there-are-4-differents-positive-integers-a-b-c-and-d-that-satisfy-b).

Could someone prove (or disprove) that for $n\geq3$? Thanks!

Comment: What about  $X=(1,2,3)$ and  $Y=(3,2,1)$ ?  To be sure I understand your question, by  $X$  equals  $Y$ you mean  $x_i=y_i \forall  i=1,\cdots,n$ ?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way of X be different of Y and still those constraints are not violated. @Nizar can you find an example that $X\neq Y$

Comment: @Nizar by $X = Y$ I mean $X\cap Y = X$ so the order of elements inside the sets are irrelevant

Comment: Okay so You are taking sets not vectors .

Comment: That's what the title says :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a look at Pythagorean triples, I found the following sets
\begin{align}
X= \{ 6, 8 , 13 \} && Y =\{5,10 ,12 \}
\end{align}
Then $\sum_{X} = 6+8+13 = 27 = 5+10+12 = \sum_{Y}$ and $6^2+8^2 =10^2$ as well as $5^2+12^2 = 13^2$.

So in general, for any $n \ge 3$, you start with $X$ and $Y$ and you add the same  $n-3$ integers greater than $40$ to both sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hetebrij

Comment: But this is only one example and not a proof that it holds generally.

Comment: It is a counterexample for the case $n \ge 3$

Comment: Ah sorry, right. :-)

Comment: Ok. But guys...if the constraints were $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^3=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^3$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 =\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2 $

Comment: @rodrigorandel That is a whole different question. But I suspect that it would be possible to find $X \neq Y$ such that the constraints holds.